# Сокращение слова "века"

Tags: орфография

Как правильно сократить слово "века" (XIX - начало ХХ в. или вв.)?

Answer (score 1):

Равняться нужно на последнее слово, именно с ним будет связано существительное "века". То есть будет "девятнадцатый - начало двадцатого века".